# Magento2.2 - How to add success message after Ajax Success?

Tags: magento2.2

I am submitting the form by ajax. It's working properly but I have one issue with the success message.

After ajax success, I have to display success message like default Magento2. How can I achieve this?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo $block->getUrl('frontname/order/save'); ?>",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text",
    data: "cancel= " + orderJSON,
    showLoader: true,
    success: function () {
    $("#" + id).remove();
    window.location.reload();
   }
});
```

Comment: I had the same issue, asked and answered here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/237973/6549

Answer (score 0):

```
define(['Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'], function (customerData) {
customerData.set('messages', {
    messages: [{
        text: 'message to display',
        type: 'success'
    }]
});});
```